# Symfony4 SwitchUserSubscriber doesn't distinguish between two users

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

in my S4 application i need the switch user "functionality" for super user. I have a form input with autocomplete to search users (available only for ROLE_SUPERADMIN) but i would like to forbid to a user to impersonate itself.  I've implemented this eventsubscriber but for both , $currentUser and $targetUser, it return the same identity (the target one). Where am i wrong?

```
<?php

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\SwitchUserEvent;

class SwitchUserSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function onSecuritySwitchUser(SwitchUserEvent $event)
    {
        $currentUser = $event->getToken()->getUser();
        $targetUser = $event->getTargetUser();

        if($currentUser->getUsername() == $targetUser->getUsername()){
            throw new UnsupportedUserException("You can't impersonate yourself");
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
           'security.switch_user' => 'onSecuritySwitchUser',
        ];
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the solution, read the code comments for explanation

```
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\SwitchUserEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\SwitchUserRole;

class SwitchUserSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @param SwitchUserEvent $event
     */
    public function onSecuritySwitchUser(SwitchUserEvent $event)
    {

        // Current user initialized to null
        $currentUser = null;
        // Gets all the roles in switching phase
        $roles = $event->getToken()->getRoles();
        // Cycles between roles
        foreach($roles as $role) {
            // SwitchUserRole it's a role of the impersonating user
            // The if statement doesn't happen in switch exit
            if ($role instanceof SwitchUserRole) {
                // Recupera l'uente
                $currentUser = $role->getSource()->getUser();
            }
        }

        // Impersonated user
        $targetUser = $event->getTargetUser();
        // If you wann be yourself raises an exception
        if(null !== $currentUser && ($currentUser->getUsername() == $targetUser->getUsername())){
            throw new UnsupportedUserException("You can't impersnate yourself");
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
           'security.switch_user' => 'onSecuritySwitchUser',
        ];
    }
}
```